# Como desabilitar um button e, para ativa-lo, deve-se clicar em um outro?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Criei uma calculadora utilizando o Windows Forms, rodou perfeitamente, porém ao clicar no button de operação antes do button de numero (para inserir um valor no visor) acontece um erro que fecha sozinho meu programa.
Queria saber como posso fazer para que inicialmente os buttons de operação fiquem desabilitados, e após o clique no button de numero fique disponível para efetuar a operação. Agradeço a ajuda..

Comment: Dentro do código que o _button_ de número executa, você pode colocar um `btnCalcular.Enabled = true;`. Sendo que você precisa deixar o valor do `Enabled` dele `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem duas **soluções:**

1 - Usar o **try** / **catch** , onde caso ocorra um erro o seu programa vai cair no **catch** e aí você mostra uma mensagem ou algo do género.

2 - Como o @Jeterson referiu, no **Load** do seu **Form** todos os botões de cálculo encontram-se desativados ( * , + , - , % ). Só depois de você clicar em um dos números para efetuar a sua operação é que estes botões vão estar **ativados** e disponíveis para ser operados.

No load do seu **Form:**

```
btnSoma.Enabled = False;
btnSubt.Enabled = False;
btnMult.Enabled = False;
btnDivid.Enabled = False;
```

Por fim, no evento **Click** dos números, quando um deles é clicado você vai ativar as **TextBox** de operações:

```
btnSoma.Enabled = True;
btnSubt.Enabled = True;
btnMult.Enabled = True;
btnDivid.Enabled = True;
```

Answer (score 2):

No construtor da sua classe form você coloca o botão para iniciar desabilitado.

```
public Calculadora(){
InicializaComponent();
btnSomar.Enabled = false;
//outros botoes que voce queira deixar desabilitados
}
```

Agora no evento click do botao de número você coloca `btnSomar.Enabled = true;`
para poder habilitar o botão.